# Slideshow using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I expect this code to work for slide show.But it shows only the last image.Can anyone please explain what went wrong?

```
    public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

String file[] 
{"/logo.png","/logo1.png","/logo2.png","/logo3.png","/logo4.png"}; 
public Midlet() throws IOException 
{
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form=new Form("SlideShow");
        start=new Command("Start",Command.OK,1);
        form.addCommand(start);
        form.setCommandListener(this);

}
public void startApp() {
    display.setCurrent(form);
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    if(c==start)
    {


    try {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
            img[i]=Image.createImage(file[i]);
            imageItem[i] = new ImageItem("Muruga",img[i] , 
ImageItem.LAYOUT_CENTER, "image not found");
            form1[i]=new Form("Images");
            form1[i].append(imageItem[i]);
            form1[i].setCommandListener(this);
            display.setCurrent(form1[i]);
            }
```

Since image should be static for some seconds,I have used System.currentTimeMillis() method

```
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
            System.out.println(i+1);
            display.setCurrent(form1[i]);
            long milli=System.currentTimeMillis();
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()<=milli+1000)
            {
                display.setCurrent(form1[i]);

            }
            if(i==4)
                destroyApp(true);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems like screen is not refreshing while commandAction does not return. Create a new Thread to switch between Forms.

Comment: @ Telmo Pimentel Mota Yeah.The thread executed properly printing the loop values correctly but images did not change.So I wrote the whole code inside startApp() function which worked perfectly.Anyway thanks for the information about why it went wrong